# How to customized default date function output in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to display the default format to like this `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss` rather than `Wed Mar 04 2020 18:18:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`as default format.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Function to diplay time</h2>

<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `toLocaleDateString`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: This is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Do you want to format the string produced when calling `Date()` without `new`? According to the spec, the format is fixed unfortunately. See https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-date-constructor-date and https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-todatestring.

Comment: I just simply want to format the output as I mentioned above. This is the output format which I want   yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss

Comment: That will be helpful for me if could do that in code snippet

Comment: You have to build it yourself in raw JavaScript: https://codepen.io/benaston/pen/JjdrpLo?editors=0012. Otherwise: use a library.

Comment: I have corrected the top answer here, so that it solves your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getDate() {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
          [
            currentDate.getFullYear(),
            currentDate.getMonth() + 1,
            currentDate.getDate()
          ].join("/") +
          " " +
          [
            currentDate.getHours(),
            currentDate.getMinutes(),
            currentDate.getSeconds()
          ].join(":");
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Function to diplay time</h2>

<button type="button"

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please check this is not working anyway.